# “Static member '…' cannot be used on instance of type '…'”

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, oop, swift4.2

I have a family of abstract classes I want to implement to perform a task depending on the instance created. But when I try to call the method using the variable declared as the base class I get  “Static member '…' cannot be used on instance of type '…'”

some pieces of the code looks like this

```
class BaseClass{
  class func theTask(){
      print("do nothing")
  }
}

class SubClassA: BaseClass{
  class func theTask(){
      print("do class A task")
  }
}

class SubClassB: BaseClass{
  class func theTask(){
      print("do class B task")
  }
}
```

The variable is declared as a property of one of my viewControllers,

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
  var theObject: BaseClass = BaseClass()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if(mysettings.selectedPort ==1){
      theObject = SubClassA()
    }else{
      theObject = SubClassB()
    }

    configureUIElements()
  }

  @IBAction func scanButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let devices = self.theObject.theTask()
  }
}
```

The line that says

```
let devices = self.theObject.theTask()
```

Is the one that gives me the error
Static member 'theTask' cannot be used on instance of type 'BaseClass'

I come from C++ so this kind of coding is very common but Swift doesn´t seems to like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are creating and using instances of the classes you have to declare `theTask` as **instance** method and override it (which you have to do in any case)

```
class BaseClass{
   func theTask(){
      print("do nothing")
   }
}

class SubClassA: BaseClass{
   override func theTask(){
      print("do class A task")
   }
}

class SubClassB: BaseClass{
   override func theTask(){
      print("do class B task")
   }
}
```

Or the other way round put the **type** into the variable and call the method on the type

```
class BaseClass{
    class func theTask(){
        print("do nothing")
    }
}

class SubClassA: BaseClass{
    override class func theTask(){
        print("do class A task")
    }
}

class SubClassB: BaseClass{
    override class func theTask(){
        print("do class B task")
    }
}

...


var theObject: BaseClass.Type = BaseClass.self

...

if mysettings.selectedPort == 1 {
  theObject = SubClassA.self
}else{
  theObject = SubClassB.self
}

...

let devices = theObject.theTask()
```

Comment: The first example worked very well! And looks cleaner, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [type(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885064-type) to accomplish that.

Following your example:

`type(of: theObject).theTask()`